# OAuth2 bearer token is not being saved in Named Credential and cannot use {!$Credential.OAuthToken}

Tags: apex, rest-api, oauth2, namedcredentials, auth-provider

I am trying to create an LWC that takes in 2 addresses from the UI and uses Fedex's Rates API to get the estimated cost.

I have the "Token Endpoint URL" but the API docs but it does not mention an "Authorize Endpoint URL" so I kept both endpoints the same in my Auth Provider.

`request.setEndpoint('callout:fedexNamedCredentialLegacy'+'/oauth/token');` works in my Apex class and I am able to successfully get a response with the bearer auth token but the Named Credential still shows "Pending".

I'm trying to use `request.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer '+'{!$Credential.OAuthToken}');` in my other method's callout but `{!$Credential.OAuthToken}` is coming back null.

**This is how my Auth Provider is set up:**

[image]

**This is how my Named Credential (Legacy) is set up:**

[image]

Comment: Try to open the Initialization link from the `Salesforce Configuration` section (bottom section in Auth. Provider)

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with legacy named credentials and FedEx but I got this going with a non-legacy named credential.

Here is the named credential:
[image: FedEx Named Credential]

And here is the external credential:
[image: FedEx External Credential]

Then you have to go whichever permission set you want to use and add the principal:
[image]

Hope that helps!